# Android YoutubePlayer to auto play Youtube videos

Tags: android

i am using YoutubePlayer API to play videos from youtube.My problem is to auto play videos starting with ads using "Youtubeplayerfragment" starting with  1.loadvideo(videoid) auto plays videos but skips ads 2.using cuevideo(videoid) cue's video but does'nt auto play.so how to auto play videos along with ads.

Answer (score 13):

Instead of player.cuevideo(videoid) use player.loadVideo(videoId)

```
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
    if (!wasRestored) {
        player.loadVideo(strYoutubeId);
    }
}
```